# Getting multiple domains in Active Directory

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, active-directory, cross-domain, windows-firewall

I have a .Net application hosted on IIS with Windows Authentication enabled.  We are in network Domain A.  Our company has a few set up of people on Domain B.  When Domain A users access this site, IE prompts with a login dialog box, where they provide Domain A user name and password.  They logs-in to the site automatically.  When Domain B users access this URL, they don't get this prompted.

I'm not sure if this is the right question... but how do I get prompt for Domain B users? What do I need to add to IIS or firewall?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To resolve the issue, I had to open up AD Users and Computers on the Server --> enable  Advanced Features --> Select the Computer Object --> Properties --> Security --> Add the Group I want to allow access to the computer (in this case, DomainA\Domain users) and allow "Allowed to Authenticate".   If you are not sure where and how to do this, you can talk to your Server Admin team.  They should know where to do these steps.

I found solution in an IIS forum in case someone is interested...

http://forums.iis.net/t/1153075.aspx?Windows+Authentication+and+Multiple+Domains